# AMP Client ID Error

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, amp-html, clientid

Trying to implement the CLIENT_ID variable at the moment (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#variable-substitution-in-links) so the link is:

```
<a id="get-started" href="https://subdomain.website.com/?client_id=CLIENT_ID(_ga)" data-amp-replace="CLIENT_ID">
```

We have also whitelisted the domain names:

```
<meta name="amp-link-variable-allowed-origin" content="https://www.website.com https://subdomain.website.com">
```

And then amended the GA code:

```
    <amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
     <script type="application/json">
      {
        "vars": {
          "account": "UA-XXXXXXX-X"
        },
        "extraUrlParams": {
          "clientId": "${clientId(_ga)}"
        },
        "triggers": {
          "trackPageview": {
            "on": "visible",
            "request": "pageview"
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
   </amp-analytics>
```

The console is reporting these errors:

```
element-service.js:63 The first argument to CLIENT_ID, the fallback Cookie name, is required:  undefined
log.js:317 Uncaught Error: The first argument to CLIENT_ID, the fallback Cookie name, is required: undefined​​​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CLIENT_ID(_ga)` instead:

```
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXXX-X"

  },
  "extraUrlParams": {
    "ampClientId": "CLIENT_ID(_ga)"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It's important to note what is happening here:

When using the `CLIENT_ID(_ga)` we're actually telling AMP analytics to generate a cookie named `_ga` and then we use it as the `extraUrlParams` which get concatenated to the URL.

It's important to note that we could create any cookie with this method, so if we would want to use a different analytics vendor we could generate whatever cookie we need, for example:

`CLIENT_ID(some_random_cookie)` would set a cookie named `some_random_cookie` with the `amp_client_id` (some hash) as the value.